# Improve performance when reading file from URL and writing it to disk

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedinputstream

I made a program which accesses some URLs and downloads the pdfs from there. The files vary between 2MB to 40MB. **The program works with no problems** but is there a way to improve the perfomance on this? For the larger files it takes a long time to do it.

The code below is the one used for reading / writing the file. This is called in a for loop with different fileNameURLPath.

```
@Override
    public void downloadFile(String fileNameURLPath, String titleCellValue) throws FileException {

        try (BufferedInputStream inputStream 
                = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(fileNameURLPath).openStream())){
            FileOutputStream fileOS = new FileOutputStream(FileConstants.MandatoryDownloadProperties.path + titleCellValue + ".pdf");
            byte data[] = new byte[32*1024];
            int byteContent;
            while((byteContent = inputStream.read(data,0 , data.length)) != -1) {   
                fileOS.write(data, 0 , byteContent);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            fileOS.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new FileException("Error while processing url. Make sure it is correct");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new FileException("Error while downloading file. Make sure the download path is correct");
        }

    }
```

I read something about Java NIO but I couldn't quite comprehend it or if it can help me in this situation

Comment: Not 100% sure (check their rules), but this may be a better fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Have you measured how long it takes? And calculated the effective throughput? And what was the result? Next, how fast is the internet where you are? And finally, how fast is the internet where those files are?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch for a 2MB file, the download is almost instant, but up to 5 minutes for a 80mb. My internet is not an issue, when I download it manualy it's instant. I don't know if the issue is from Springer(the site that I take it, here is an example of a book [link](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2Fb97469)

Comment: Try your current code on your local network. Ideally wired ethernet. Both machines on the same network. If the performance is consistent blame "the internet". If the performance is inconsistent let us know what the variance is.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I think you were right , because I was on Wifi the connection was fluctuating. Now it's better. But question still remains is there other techniques that can be used beside the one presented? API or threading or other library? I ask this for pure knowledge curiosity

Comment: Compression. If the data is highly redundant. UDP might perform better than TCP. But you can't shove an elephant through a cat door (at least not quickly).